# Best way to mutate a private vector in a class

Tags: c++, class, private, mutators

I have a question about better programming practice. Say, I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {
public: 
    vector<double> data() { return data_; }
    void set_data(int index, double value) { data_[index] = value; }
private:
    vector<double> data_;
};
```

I have the private vector `data_` and accessor/mutator functions to that. Using `operator=` in case of public `data_` is very convenient. However, I need to make the `data_` private and access/mutate it through member functions. But I am not sure of the best way to construct the mutator function. The best way I have so far is the one in the example. Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't see why the one in the example ISN'T good... one small improvement would be to make the mutator in the struct just a prototype, and have the function lower in the program.

Comment: more context would help.  given only this, the best approach would be to say `using MyClass = std::vector<double>;`

Comment: Your class, as written, is as good as a freestanding `std::vector<double>` and tells us nothing about what you're trying to achieve. That makes it hard to give advice about "better way".

Comment: Don't make classes just for the sake of it. Every class should have one single, distinct purpose and responsibility. If your class has too many responsibilities, split it. If it has none, remove it.

Comment: As it stands, your `data()` method should be `const` and you have no way of setting the size of your vector. How do you want to create this class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you want to do with the class but I would suggest:

```
double getAt(size_t index) const { return data_.at(index); }
void setAt(size_t index, double value) { data_.at(index) = value; }
```

This has the advantage that you could change the internal implementation of the class, e.g to use a different STL container, and you would not need to change the interface. Note that the getter is `const`.

If performance is critical and you trust the callers then you can omit the bounds checking:

```
double getAt(size_t index) const { return data_[index]; }
void setAt(size_t index, double value) { data_[index] = value; }
```

But it may be useful to be able to set the whole vector and you don't mind exposing the implementation, in which case you might want something like:

```
void setData(std::vector<double> data) { data_ = std::move(data); }
```

Note that `setData` takes the vector by value and moves it into the private member variable this means that if the caller passes an rvalue then no copy is made.

If you need to get the whole vector, you have a choice. If the vector is not too large, performance is not critical or you need to make a copy anyway then return by value is fine and would be my first choice:

```
std::vector<double> getData() const { return data_; }
```

Otherwise return by reference:

```
const std::vector<double>& getData() const { return data_; }
std::vector<double>& getData() { return data_ }
```

But be aware that this is completely breaking encapsulation, particularly the non-const version.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest methods of providing access to the data.

```
double& at(size_t index) { return data_[index]; }
double const& at(size_t index) const { return data_[index]; }
```

Comment: This looks a bit too much like "returning handles to object internals" to me.

Comment: @ChrisDrew That is almost true. The only difference is that you can change the internal holder of the data to an array of `double` and still be able to support the interface. If you went crazy, you could even change the internal data to an `std::map` and still be able to support that interface.1

Comment: @R Sahu: True, but there is more to encapsulation than just that though. We also want to protect private data. Scott Meyers says that the problem with the second method is that it can lead to 'dangling handles' see http://ideone.com/McIGCp. Scott does go on to admit that operator[] on `vector` returns a reference to the data in the container but that "...such functions are the exception, not the rule".

Comment: @ChrisDrew All STL containers return references to the data they hold. It's clear that these are matters of opinion. The risk of dangling pointers is part and parcel of programming in C/C++. You have to know the potential pitfalls are and use your class interface with the risks that come with them. Returning objects by value works great for basic types and not too large PODs. They break down when you have containers and complex aggregate objects.

Comment: @R Sahu: But you have not been tasked with writing a generic STL container. In this case you are only returning a `double` so why not return it by value?  It will be just as fast and less prone to errors.

Comment: @R Sahu, but agreed these are matters of opinion, I may edit my answer to make the performance implications of returning the whole vector by value clear.